# Is it possible to link from 2 different domains to the same app using dynamic links?

Tags: deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-app-indexing

I have 2 domains and one single app but would link from both domains to app-pages via Deep-Links.

Is it possible to link from e. g. both static.domain.com and content.domain.com into the same app with dynamic links?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you could add many domain as many as you want.
Just add your domains inside manifest.

```
<data android:host="static.domain.com" android:scheme="http"/>
<data android:host="static.domain.com" android:scheme="https"/>
<data android:host="content.domain.com" android:scheme="http"/>
<data android:host="content.domain.com" android:scheme="https"/>
```

So, the code look like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="static.domain.com" android:scheme="http"/>
    <data android:host="static.domain.com" android:scheme="https"/>
    <data android:host="content.domain.com" android:scheme="http"/>
    <data android:host="content.domain.com" android:scheme="https"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Do not forget to verify your domains by adding assetlinks.json inside .well-known folder. Ensure that  is accessible using `https://static.domain.com/.wll-known/assetlinks.json` and `https://content.domain.com.com/.wll-known/assetlinks.json`. Should using https for verifying your domain.

Cheers